# Trigger internal button of datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I've a question about this specific datetimepicker 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Is it possible to trigger "now" button in this datetimepicker to change hours only when I push this?

This is my html

```
<div class="col-md-9 datapicker-in-left">
<p class="input-group editEvent-input-date">                                                            
    <input  type="text" 
            id="beginDate" 
            class="form-control field-height datePickerWidth"
            ng-style ="fieldRequired"
            ng-model="event.beginDate" 
            datetime-picker="{{picker.format}}" 
            button-bar="picker.buttonBar"
            timepicker-options="picker.timepickerOptions"
            is-open="popup1.opened"
            ng-blur="checkDates()"
            ng-selected ="required()"
            ng-change="checkDateField()"
            ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}"
            datetimepicker-neutral-timezone="{{timezone}}"
            check-profile="{{profileItems.visibleFieldsList['beginEvent']}}" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-default form-control date-but"
            ng-click="openPopup(popup1)" 
            check-profile="{{profileItems.visibleFieldsList['beginEvent']}}"
            check-readonly="{{isBlockedEvent || readOnly}}">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
<!-- <input class="date-widths" type="datetime-local" step="60" ng-model="startDate">-->
```

this is the only part when i set the property of datetimepicker

```
$scope.picker = {
    format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    buttonBar : {
        show: true,
        now: {show: true, text: $translate.instant('DATA_PICKER_BUTTON_NOW')},
        today: {show: true, text: $translate.instant('DATA_PICKER_BUTTON_TODAY')},
        clear: {show: true, text: $translate.instant('DATA_PICKER_BUTTON_CLEAR')},
        date: {show: true, text: $translate.instant('DATA_PICKER_BUTTON_DATE')},
        time: {show: true, text: $translate.instant('DATA_PICKER_BUTTON_TIME')},
        close: {show: true, text: $translate.instant('DATA_PICKER_BUTTON_CLOSE')}
    },
    timepickerOptions : {showSeconds: true, readonlyInput:true, showMeridian: false}
}
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor english

Comment: It's not clear what `this` is? An example of what you'd want to happen and what currently happens would be ideal.

Comment: Yes, at this time, when I press this button, set the system date but I want to change this behaviour based on the timezone of profiling